# Chrome Packaged App: Open Website in New Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm updating one of my chrome apps to just launch the web app (why? I don't have the time to continue updating the chrome app, alone with the desktop apps for offline use)

Here's what the manifests starts with...

```
"app": {
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   }
},
```

I just want it to open a new tab to the website now instead of launching a packaged app. So I tried the following...

```
"app": {
   "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
   }
},
```

An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

Please specify background subsection of app section in the manifest.

```
"app": {
   "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
   },
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   }
},
```

An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

Application specifications for packaged and hosted apps are incompatible. Please refer to manifest specification.
The manifest may not contain a launch object inside the app object.

So I decided to stick with just the background script and try to just create a new tab that way.

**background.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html',
    {
      id: 'mainWindow',
      innerBounds: {
        'width': 800,
        'height': 600
      }
    }
  );
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
  var a    = document.createElement("a")
  a.href   = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
  a.target = "_blank"
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
</script>
```

I was finally able to successfully add a new tab with...

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/")
})
```

in my `background.js` script.

However the following error occurs...

[image]

I clicked on the ["Learn More"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?p=e_awsnap&rd=1) button but that too gave me the same "Aw, Snap!" page

Does anyone know why I can't open a new tab in a chrome packaged app?

and

How am I suppose to open a new tab in a chrome packaged app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `chrome.browser.openTab({ url: "" }, callback)` with the `"browser"` permission.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser#method-openTab

Comment: I swear I tried this before. I went back and forgot the "browser" permission. Thanks